# ひらがなで書くかわりに、カタカナで書く中国とかんごく

Tags: words

Why are the Japanese names for the countries "China" and "Korea" written in Hiragana instead of the usual katakana?

Comment: 中国 and 韓国 are usually written in kanji, not hiragana.

Comment: 韓国 is read かん**こ**く.

Comment: 監獄 じゃあるまいしね(笑)。

Comment: see this [Why are some country names written in kanji and yet others are written in katakana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42443/why-are-some-country-names-written-in-kanji-and-yet-others-are-written-in-kataka#:~:text=About%20150%20years%20ago%20or,for%20any%20new%20foreign%20concepts.)